# COPY records from table on one database to another Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, copy, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just had to have my work laptop re-imaged and I lost a simple query I had to copy records from a table on one database to the same table on another database in Oracle SQL Developer.  Can't seem to find the same query online.  I did come up with this similar one, which works, but it asks for the user name and password for each database, one at a time.  The previous query didn't do that, it just ran and was done.  Anyone familiar with query that would work as long as you are connected to both databases already?  Here is the one I have working that asks for the user names and passwords -

```
COPY FROM USER@HOSTNAME.company.com:9999/production TO USER@HOSTNAME.company.com:9999/development -
INSERT DATA_RAW USING (SELECT * FROM DATA_RAW WHERE TRANDATE BETWEEN '01-JUN-20' AND '30-JUN-20');
```

Comment: Can you create a database link? Or are you looking for some SQL Developer built-in feature?

Comment: I had a query very similar to the one above which just ran in SQL Developer.  The one above does run, but it pops up four different windows - first it asks you to input the database copying from (which it auto-populates), then it asks for the password, then it does the same for the other database.  The query I had did not do that.  Just ran.  It's just a bit inconvenient entering that info every time I run it.

Comment: Can you create a database link though? You tagged SQL Developer so I wondered if you meant some specific feature of that tool rather than just a query that would run anywhere. A `copy` command is not a query though so it is not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on my 11gXE database; copying data between users in the same database, though (don't have any remote database available at the moment):

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL>
SQL> copy from scott/tiger@xe to mike/lion@xe replace dept -
> using select * from dept;

Array fetch/bind size is 15. (arraysize is 15)
Will commit when done. (copycommit is 0)
Maximum long size is 80. (long is 80)
Table DEPT dropped.

Table DEPT created.

   4 rows selected from scott@xe.
   4 rows inserted into DEPT.
   4 rows committed into DEPT at mike@xe.

SQL>
```

Comment: My query above does work, but for some reason pops up a window to enter the connection from, then that DB password, then the connection to and the password.  Four separate little windows each time I run it.  It didn't do that before.  But I did have to download the latest version of Oracle SQL Developer, so maybe that's a change with the latest version?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I used SQL*Plus for this demo.